# C# How to get a screenshot of a window?

Tags: c#, window, screenshot

I'm getting a screenshot of the full screen using this method

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
     graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
         Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
         0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
         CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
```

Now what I would like to do is improve this in a way I can get the screenshot of some specific window.

I just know a couple things about it:

1. The title.
2. The main process from where it's created (and this process can create an undetermined number of windows).

It's not necessarily the active window.

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: do you have the window handle? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms536160(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Sayse If he doesn't, he can just loop through the windows and find the right one.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - I know, I was just pointing in the right direction :) I left that out intentionally as its a lazy way to do it if the window handle is already available

Comment: I think you'll have to use the Windows API [`EnumChildWindows()`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html) to find the handle of the window you're interested in, and then proceed from there.

Comment: Need some extra help, finally got it working but only work with parent windows, the window I want to capture is a child one, and when I ss it I get the content of the top window.  http://pastebin.com/EdSZD8A0